# Can I change the order of these OpenGL / Win32 calls?

Tags: opengl, windows

I've been adapting the [NeHe OpenGL/Win32 code](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=01) to be more object-oriented and I don't like the way some of the calls are structured.

The example has the following pseudo-structure:

> Register window class
> **Change display settings with a DEVMODE**
> Adjust window rect
> Create window
> Get DC
> **Find closest matching pixel format**
> **Set the pixel format to closest match**
> **Create rendering context**
> **Make that context current**
> Show the window
> Set it to foreground
> Set it to having focus
> **Resize the GL scene**
> **Init GL**

The points in **bold** are what I want to move into a rendering class (the rest are what I see being pure Win32 calls) but I'm not sure if I can call them *after* the Win32 calls.
Essentially what I'm aiming for is to encapsulate the Win32 calls into a `Platform::Initiate()` type method and the rest into a sort of `Renderer::Initiate()` method.

So my question essentially boils down to: **"Would OpenGL allow these methods to be called in this order?"**

> Register window class
> Adjust window rect
> Create window
> Get DC
> Show the window
> Set it to foreground
> Set it to having focus
>
> **Change display settings with a DEVMODE**
> **Find closest matching pixel format**
> **Set the pixel format to closest match**
> **Create rendering context**
> **Make that context current**
> **Resize the GL scene**
> **Init GL**

(obviously passing through the appropriate window handles and device contexts)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried it, to see if it works? The only thing that I could see happening is the DC being affected by the DEVMODE. You also may want to accept some previous answers.

Comment: I haven't built it yet I was exploring for advice before committing the time. Also 'working' isn't the result I need, for example it may work now then when I add complexity a serious error may occur due to not initialising the GL window in the appropriate manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off I don't see any reason why you couldn't, unless some of the operations depend on values produced by earlier operations. An easy way to "try it and see" is to simply re-order the calls where there are now, without actually implementing any of the extra abstraction layers you want. That should let you know if anything is trivially wrong that I'm forgetting.

If there is a more subtle problem, it is likely to be in an interaction between your new proposed setup and your other code that you have not shown, so we couldn't really diagnose it reliably now anyhow. You can always debug later -- don't be afraid of making the wrong decision now. That's why we refactor.

I wouldn't necessarily show the window before it is prepared for rendering, though.

You also might consider not separating the Win32 and GL calls, but just encapsulating them together. They are quite tightly tied together on a practical level -- especially if you are not *currently* developing your code against multiple OSs, it can neatly tie up your higher-level graphics API.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, the last point is certainly something im considering.